# Landscape and Portrait View getting buttons to Right Side

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera

I am writing a Camera App in which i want to show buttons at bottom while user view app in a Portrait View and want to show to right side, when use Landscape view

But in my app still i am getting buttons to right side, in both views (Portrait and Landscape)

**activity_camera.xml:-**

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash_background" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/angel_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gallery" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCapture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:background="@drawable/capture" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide two different layout files, one for portrait and one for landscape.

Specifically, you should put your portrait layout xml into res/layout and your landscape layout xml into res/layout-land. Note, that both files must have the same name.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html for further information.

Comment: The Android system decides which one to use. This is one of the reasons that your Activities get restarted whenever you rotate your device.

Comment: To place the buttons at the bottom, use `android:layout_alignParentBottom`. If you want both side by side at the bottom, you should consider placing them into a horizontal LinearLayout and place the LinearLayout at the bottom of the RelativeLayout using `android:layout_alignParentBottom`.

Comment: I accepted your answer, but whenever i view camera in Portrait mode getting : Unfortunately App has stopped

Comment: Has this to do with the changes to the layout? If so, please add stack-trace from LogCat to your question. Otherwise you should create a new question.